# Problems with downloading infromation from Google Trends in R

Tags: r, google-trends, gtrendsr

I tried to download infromation from Google trends to object in R. Therea are several packages for it but I decided to use Gtrends. I met with unexpected problem and there is no information about it.

```
library(gtrendsR)
> google.trends = gtrends(c("blu-ray"), gprop = "web", time = "all")

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url) : 
  schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
```

I guess there are some problems with connection but I dont know how to solve it. Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance.

Version of R: 3.5.0.
Version of package: 1.4.1

Comment: All I can get from any of the examples in ?gtrends is a `Error: widget$status_code == 200 is not TRUE` message. Something is broken and its not you or me...

Comment: I suspect google have changed their service, since there doesn't seem to be an official google trends API. I just got a python google trends package running, that was updated a few days ago, `gtrendsR` is a few months old now.